# Riddle - Socks that may or may not be puppets

Tags: riddle, word

I'm surprisingly standard, 
But can ban if required. 
Found in tea, less often than more, 
I might also clear your sock drawer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a similar vein to [Alconja's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/11089/5373), how about this?

> A FLAG.

*I'm surprisingly standard,*

> A flag can also be called a standard (as in battle standard)

*But can ban if required.*

> ... or a banner, which can also mean "one who bans". A ban on an SE user's account may result from a flag being raised by another user.

*Found in tea, less often than more,*

> This is probably a golf reference: "tea" is a homophone of "tee" and flags are found on golf courses (on the tee perhaps? I don't know enough about golf to say).

*I might also clear your sock drawer.*

> As Alconja says, SE moderators sometimes have to delete sockpuppet accounts - the fact of sockpuppeting may be drawn to their attention by a flag raised by another user.

Another possibility (even more similar to Alconja's answer) is

> a [MODERATOR](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators): they can ban other users, delete sockpuppet accounts, and probably drink tea.

I can't make that fit the first line though.

Comment: @d'alar'cop - can you explain the "Found in tea" line?

Comment: @Alconja Indeed, the paper thing at the end of the string is a _flag_... sometimes the thing falls in my tea >:(

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to take a stab and say:

> Moderate

*I'm surprisingly standard,*

> Moderate as a adjective means average, modest, standard, etc

*But can ban if required.*

> As a verb, to moderate, might include banning someone (e.g. from a forum)

*Found in tea, less often than more,*

> The letters "tea" and "more" are contained in moderate, but there's less in tea.

*I might also clear your sock drawer.*

> Moderators on stack exchange sometimes have to deal with sock puppet accounts, and delete/clear them (noting the hint in the title)

Comment: Wow, great work! +1 very close in many ways... especially the last line

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be:

> Alcohol!

I'm surprisingly standard,

> Alcohol is very standard

But can ban if required.

> Prohibition of alcohol in the US in 1920's

Found in tea, less often than more,

> Sometimes(less often than more often) people drink tea with some sort of alcohol in it

I might also clear your sock drawer.

> If we use it as a figurative reference to the mind(as *[Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/7307/c%E1%B4%8F%C9%B4%E1%B4%8F%CA%80-ob%CA%80%C9%AA%E1%B4%87%C9%B4)* suggested), then small doses of alcohol can clear your mind (large doses will mess it up tho')
>  Another figurative meaning of *Sock Drawer* could be [*an area in your closet designated for pornography storage. Could contain socks*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sock%20drawer), so with alcohol you can get rid of the stains
>  Or if it's the real sock drawer, you may use alcohol to disinfect/clear the drawer (if you are the dirty one, haha)

Comment: For line 4 why not have a "ex"alcoholic grampa hiding booze in there? Anyway, +1 but there is a nicer more riddlish fit

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> Honey

I'm surprisingly standard,

> In a lot of standard family stories, the husband calls his wife honey.

But can ban if required.

> The wife could restrict her husband or children from doing something.

Found in tea, less often than more,

> Some people add honey to their tea, instead of the more common sugar.

I might also clear your sock drawer.

> Your wife or mother might clear your sock drawer.

Comment: Interesting... I like this +1 but the answer is a much stronger fit

Answer (score 4):

I'll have a go at this and guess:

> A string

I'm surprisingly standard

> A piece of string is about as 'standard' as things get.

But can ban if required.

> In certain situations, anything with strings is prohibited for safety reasons (plenty murder stories with guitar/piano strings, ...)

Found in tea, less often than more,

> String from a teabag

I might also clear your sock drawer.

> Well, if you find too many strings in your sock drawer, your socks have seen better days, and should be cleared from the drawer.

Just a guess ofcourse, I think so far most of us interpret the second line as 'being banned' then actually 'banning', so in doubt there.

Comment: Interesting +1 but the second and fourth line are unconvincing :p

Answer (score 4):

It is

> a plastic bag

I'm surprisingly standard,

> plastic bags tend to be mass-produced, think grocery bags, etc.

But can ban if required.

> plastic bags have been banned (or at least regulated) in municipalities due to littering and their environmental impact.

Found in tea, less often than more,

> Some new brands of tea are using special nylon mesh bags

I might also clear your sock drawer.

> You can toss all your socks into a bag when you're about to travel.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer:

> Caffeine

## Explanation

I'm surprisingly standard,

> You find it everywhere--in coffee, tea, and some sodas.

BUt can ban if required.

> It *is* technically a drug--so ODing on it could result in a ban?

Found in tea, less often than more,

> It is found in small doses (if present at all) in tea.

I might also clear your sock drawer.

> We can take "sock drawer" as a figurative reference to the mind (as it is often used). Then, caffeine can "clear" your mind, allowing you to stay awake for a longer period of time.

Comment: +1 Very creative. I like the caffeine boost to help you do chores! lol But there is another solution which is a tighter fit..

Comment: @d'alar'cop Thanks :) I'll be working on finding your "tighter fit"

Answer (score 3):

Ok i want to give another try/(last try may be)

Is it

> Sugar

I'm surprisingly standard,

> Sugar is surprisingly standard,

But can ban if required.

> Everyone knows which sugar is banned (br*wn sugar)

Found in tea, less often than more,

> some people avoid it in tea,some may like tea with more sugar

I might also clear your sock drawer.

> May be Sugar stimulants used to clear sock drawer..

Answer (score 0):

I think answer is

> Nicotine

I'm surprisingly standard

> we hardly can find it in stores

But can ban if required.

> govt might ban foods/drinks which contains it

Found in tea, less often than more,

> tea contains it in very small amount

I might also clear your sock drawer.

> if taken in large quantity blocks the action of autonomic nerve,smaller amount may simulate brains clearing sock drawer.

How about that???

Comment: That is a bit of stretch mate.. +1 for effort